# Audio Output coming from both headphones and laptop speakers!

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, speakers

Everything was all right for a while, but recently my laptop's sound is coming form both the speakers as well as headphones (when plugged in). The volume in headphones is optimal to the volume I've set while the volume from speakers is a bit low.

Enabling Auto-Mute from `alsamixer` fixes it but when I re-plug the headphones, I face the problem again and I have to enable it again.
Can anyone help?